# Can you make Visual Studio 12 output .o files instead of .obj?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker, assimp

I'm trying to use Assimp to load 3d object files using the file format `.obj`. Now that doesn't play very nice with the VC++ compiler and linker, which uses the `.obj` format as linker objects. Can I make Visual Studio use the file extension `.o` instead?

Answer (score 1):

The /Fo flag

> If you do not use this option, the object file uses the base name of the source file and the .obj extension. You can use any name and extension you want, but the recommended convention is to use .obj.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb8e9b8y.aspx

Comment: And the linker doesn't care about the extension.